# Dependency Injection not working in Angular 2 starter application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

When I try to inject ANY dependency I get a weird error

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'stack' of undefined
at NoProviderError.set [as stack] (errors.js:64)
at assignAll (zone.js:704)
at NoProviderError.ZoneAwareError (zone.js:775)
at NoProviderError.BaseError [as constructor] (errors.js:26)
at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (reflective_errors.js:53)
at new NoProviderError (reflective_errors.js:102)
at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (reflective_injector.js:994)
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (reflective_injector.js:1031)
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (reflective_injector.js:981)
at ReflectiveInjector_.get (reflective_injector.js:743)
at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (ng_module_factory.js:149)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.injectorGet (view.js:152)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.injectorGet (view.js:580)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_AppComponent_Host0.createInternal (host.ngfactory.js:15)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.createHostView (view.js:108)
```

I have just used the Angular-Cli ng new PROJECT_NAME_HERE command.

Inside of my app.component.ts all I have is

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.sass']
})
export class AppComponent {

 constructor(
   private formBuilder: FormBuilder
 ) {
 }

}
```

Edit: 
The error I was receiving was because of an issue from v0.7.5 of zone.js,
and like user3492940 & Santanu Biswas stated I also needed to import the ReactiveFormsModule, into my app.module

Comment: Did you already load the module in app.module? ReactiveFormsModule

Comment: I have the FormsModule imported, what else would I need to import? Nvm found it I need to import ReactiveFormsModule like you said

Comment: Glad it helped. The Angular 2 team should really work on their documentation. Things are just not very clear at this moment. A lot of important details are not being documented on their website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make downgrade zone.js to 0.7.4

```
npm install --save zone.js@0.7.4
```

It's problem in `0.7.5` version. [Issue #595](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/595)

Comment: Thank you so much both your and user3492940's answers combined made it work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to import `ReactiveFormsModule` from `@angular/forms` in your `AppModule` and also include it in `imports` list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still relatively new with Angular 2 components but looking at your component, i think you need moduleId: module.id,

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.sass']
})
```